# Woo Commerce pubKey+publicIP (URI)?

Tags: lightning-network

I have integrated my bitcoin lightning network node with the Woo Commerce plugin available on the " https://github.com/ElementsProject/woocommerce-gateway-lightning" .

But facing trouble to get payment on my generated invoice .So somebody recommended to connect to WooCommerce Shopping Store.

Can anybody help in finding pubKey+publicIP (URI) for WooCommerce Shopping Store. I found it on Internet but could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

You should only need to connect to any of the nodes in the Lightning network and it should take care of learning about the rest of the network. So my suggestion would be to take any node on https://lnmainnet.gaben.win/, look at its details, and if it has a public key and IP associated just connect to that one.